# ReactJS (create-react-app) run on port 80

Tags: apache, reactjs, server

Can somebody explain how to run my reactJS app on port 80, without specifying port

currently it works on   www.mydomain.com:3001 but I want it to be visible when I go to www.mydomain.com

I can't find the solution on create-react-app docs website so I'm asking here.

If I run application with

```
sudo npm start
```

I get error that something is already using port 80 (I did specify PORT= 80)

Thanks

Comment: By default `npm` does not have `root` privilege. That means, If you try to run any application which uses port below than `1024` port, you need a `sudo` access. If that is the case, you can run your `create-react-app` with `sudo PORT=80 npm start`. That should do the job. Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

you have to specify PORT env variable to run on port 80 `PORT=80 npm run start`

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows environments.

Comment: On windows, `set PORT=80` should do the same thing

Comment: using `sudo PORT=80 npm run start`

Comment: you can use `npm run build` command to build a production-ready app. You can host the folder created inside build directory to nginx or any other server which can run it on port 80.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to run npm with sudo privilege. Better to run a local tunnel from react server's port to port 80, that way only the tunnel needs sudo.